# CloudFront Error 'CloudFront attempted to establish a connection with the origin'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

I've an application running in AWS. CloudFront is enabled.

My application is using HTTP. Also, Origin Protocol Policy is configured as 'HTTP' in CloudFront.

But sometimes I see this error:

```
ERROR
The request could not be satisfied.
CloudFront attempted to establish a connection with the origin, but either 
the attempt failed or the origin closed the connection. 
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
```

It would be great if anyone could help me solve this.

Comment: What is the origin configuration? An S3 or custom origin?

Comment: @PopoiMenenet It is custom origin

Comment: @RajKumar S3/EC2/my desktop machine can be used as a custom origin. Is it a bare-metal computer ? can you post your `curl -I <custom-origin>` ?

Comment: @kintuparantu The API resides in AWS EC2 instance which is routed via CloudFront CDN. I'm able to curl the custom origin but it's returning the above error when hit via CloudFront

Comment: possible reasons could be: CF is communicating to EC2 on different port, or the EC2 is hosting the application on non-default port. Is the port 80 on both EC2 and CF ?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience this has been caused by the default read timeout on the Cloudfront endpoint. The default is 30 seconds but can be raised to 60 seconds. If you haven't already, it is possible to output logs from cloudfront to an S3 bucket which you can examine for further information.

If your payload is big, the timeout is a likely cause.

Additionally, if you have built your Cloudfront endpoint using Cloudformation, the template property you will need to change is:

`Properties/DistributionConfig/Origins[]/CustomOriginConfig/OriginReadTimeout`